# Validate UK postcode using regular expression in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Below is the list of valid postcodes:

```
A1 1AA
A11 1AA
AA1 1AA
AA11 1AA
A1A 1AA
BFPO 1
BFPO 11
BFPO 111
```

I tried with `(([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})\ ([0-9][A-Z]{2}))|(GIR\ 0AA)$` but it is not working. Could you please help me with proper query to validate all the postcode formats.

Comment: Neither `BFPO 1` nor `BFPO 11` are valid UK post codes. The inward part is exactly three characters.

Comment: `BFPO 111` isn't valid either, the inward part always ends with two letters.

Comment: Space doesn't need to be escaped. Then, you are searching for one or two letters followed by one or two digits - that is simply not the correct pattern (even you have A1A 1AA among your examples - that does not end in a digit).

Comment: Do you just want to validate **formats** (as you say, finally, at the end of your question), or the postcodes themselves? Not all strings that follow all the format rules are in fact valid postcodes. If you are interested in the postcodes themselves, it would be better if you would have a table of actual codes and you would compare against this table. Otherwise a lot of "fake" codes will be validated, only because they follow the proper format.

Comment: For homework, a regex validation is fine, but in commerical applications it's better to verify against a database that holds all valid postal codes. Complete lists are available https://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php [CSV, 64,2 MB] or can be simply generated from openstreetmap.

Comment: hi, this is our project requirement. So I need to validate above all formats. A - [A-Z] can be any alphabet and 1 [0-9] can be any digit.

Answer (score 2):

First, rather than guessing based on the set of data at hand, [let's look at what UK postcodes are](https://web.archive.org/web/20120716211307/http://www.royalmail.com/delivery/mail-advice/postcodes-addresses-explained).

> EC1V 9HQ
>
> The first one or two letters is the postcode area and it identifies the main Royal Mail sorting office which will process the mail. In this case EC would go to the Mount Pleasant sorting office in London.
>
> The second part is usually just one or two numbers but for some parts of London it can be a number and a letter. This is the postcode district and tells the sorting office which delivery office the mail should go to.
>
> This third part is the sector and is usually just one number. This tells the delivery office which local area or neighbourhood the mail should go to.
>
> The final part of the postcode is the unit code which is always two letters. This identifies a group of up to 80 addresses and tells the delivery office which postal route (or walk) will deliver the item.

Digesting that...

1. 1 or 2 letters.
2. A number and maybe an alphanumeric.
3. A space.
4. "Usually" a number, but I can't find any instances otherwise.
5. 2 letters.

```
\A[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\d[[:alnum:]]? \d[[:alpha:]]{2}\z
```

We can't use `\w` because that contains an underscore.

I used the more exact `\A` and `\z` over `^` and `$` because `\A` and `\z` match the exact beginning and end of the string, whereas `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line. `$` in particular is tolerant of a trailing newline.

---

Of course, there are special cases. XXXX 1ZZ for various overseas territories, XXXX is enumerated.

```
\A(ASCN|STHL|TDCU|BBND|BIQQ|FIQQ|PCRN|SIQQ|TKCA) 1ZZ\z
```

Then a couple of really special cases.

- GIR 0AA for [Girobank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girobank).
- AI-2640 for Anguilla.

```
\A(AI-2640|GIR 0AA)\z
```

Put them all together into one big `(...|...|...)` mess. It's good to build the query in three pieces and put it together with the `x` modifier to ignore whitespace.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(
    postcode,
    '\A
     (
      [[:alpha:]]{1,2}\d[[:alnum:]]?\ \d[[:alpha:]]{2}\z   |
      (ASCN|STHL|TDCU|BBND|BIQQ|FIQQ|PCRN|SIQQ|TKCA)\ 1ZZ  |
      (AI-2640|GIR\ 0AA)
     )
     \z',
    'x'
)
```

Or you can make the basic regex less strict and accept 2-4 alphanumerics for the first part. Then there's only the special case for Anguilla to worry about.

```
\A([[:alnum:]]{2,4} \d[[:alpha:]]{2}|AI-2640)\z
```

On the downside, this will let in post codes that don't exist. On the up side, you don't have to keep tweaking for additional special cases. That's probably fine for this level of filtering.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55544, `\z` is not supported (but `\Z` means what `\z` should mean, and `\A` is weird).

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix001.htm#SQLRF55540, `[:` `:]` is supported. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions162.htm#SQLRF06300 uses `[[:alpha:]]` in an example (but it also claims `[s|r|p]` is how you match `s` or `r` or `p`, so I don't know how trustworthy it is).

Comment: Google-ing for the documentation surely would have taken much less time than writing this reply. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDJGBGG

Comment: @mathguy Oh wow, that page lists `\A`, `\Z`, `\z` as supported with their usual meanings (different from what I found), but it misdocuments `$`. Someone at Oracle should proofread their regexp documentation.

Comment: @Melpomene - plenty of "documentation bugs" at Oracle, it seems its practitioners (of which I am not one) are very well aware of it. Corrected though in more recent versions, for example https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012

Comment: From the docs, it doesn't look like there's support for non-capturing groups `(?...)`?

Comment: @Schwern - That is my understanding as well. They would be quite helpful.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to simply validate against a UK Postcode database?

Comment: @BobC You'd need to get one, I don't know if they're free. And make a table for it. And load it in. And keep it up to date. If you need that level of accuracy, that would be the way to go. But for a basic sanity check its probably overkill. Depends on what the OP is doing with this.

Comment: @Schwern. Of course you are correct. But I don't think the postcodes change that often. It's been a while since I've worked with UK postcodes, but many applications that lookup US Zip codes, clearly have more than just a sanity check of the format; for example, they will validate the Zip code and the city match. This makes the application far more useful.

Comment: @Schwern  A quick Goole search came up with https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Comment: @BobC That's 1,738,221 rows. Again, it depends on how accurate you need to be.

Comment: @Schwern Correct again. But it's a much simpler approach. It caters for the special cases, etc. I'm not a big fan of REGEX; one, it's slow and two, it's hard to read. I'm a big proponent of simple. Simple is easy to implement and maintain. Anyway, that's my advice/thoughts, which is worth exactly what was paid ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
FUNCTION find_postCode( txt IN varchar2 ) return varchar2 is 
    pc VARCHAR2( 1000 ) := '([[:upper:]]{1,2}[[:digit:]]{1,2}|[[:upper:]]{1}[[:digit:]]{1}[[:upper:]]{1}|[[:upper:]]{3})[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]{1}[[:upper:]]{2}';
BEGIN 
    IF regexp_like(txt,'(^|[[:blank:]]+)' || pc || '($|[[:blank:]]+)') THEN 
        RETURN regexp_substr(txt, pc);
    END IF;
    RETURN '';
END find_postCode;
```